# Al abrir un pdf con php en el titulo aparece el nombre del script php

Tags: php, pdf

Buen día!
Tengo el siguiente código para abrir un pdf vía `sftp` y mostrarlo (inline).
Todo funciona bien, pero arriba a la izquierda sale el nombre del script `php` (por ej "`miscript.php`") en lugar del nombre del archivo (`$srcFile`).
Para hacer download funciona correctamente.

```
<?
... 
$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$ruta_destino_actual/$srcFile", 'rb');
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename=$srcFile");
fpassthru($stream);
...
?>
```

Alguna solución?
Gracias!

Comment: A que te refieres con arriba en la izquierda? Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de que te ocurre?

Comment: Si lo estás mostrando inline el nombre de la página será la del script efectivamente. PD: No has adjuntado el código que mencionas.

Comment: Gracias! Perdón, pero es mi primera pregunta acá! Ahí edité y agregué el código.

Comment: Hola. Debes hacer varias cosas: 1. en header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename=$srcFile"); debes cambiar $srcFile por el nombre que deseas mostrar para el archivo. 2. Empotrarlo en un elemnto IFrame cuyo src apunte al scritp que sirve el pdf de modo que todo quede anidado. 3. luego de servir el pdf el script debe terminar abruptamente así: fpassthru($stream); fclose($stream); exit(); Al servirlo anidado en un IFrame la página exterior (contenedora) muestra todo lo demás que deba ver el usuario.